# How get all cookies in the given url using javascript or selenium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, firefox-addon

Basically i want to access all cookies in a given **url** . For example i have attached image [image: cookie]

I need to access this data. is it possible to call firebug **api** to get cookie ?
Is there any method from selenium ?
I tried `document.cookie` . not working as expected .

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
  // http://www.testsite.com/cookies.shtml
  var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
  if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
    var cookie_value = cookie_string.match ( '(^|;)[\s]*' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)' );
    return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
  }
  return '' ;
}
```

and then use this function to get cookie

**for eg**

```
cookieValue = get_cookie( "mycookies" );  //here mycookies is cookie name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cookies using Python and Selenium by using the following code -

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromebinary)
driver.get(url)
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in self.driver.get_cookies():
    print cookie['name'], cookie['value']
```